# Equivalence of two definitions of finite order function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help showing that this definition

> An entire function () is said to have finite order if there exist
> positive constants $c$ and $n$ such that $|f(z)| \leq c e^{{|z|}^n}$

… and this one…

> An entire function $f(z)$ is said to have finite order if
>
> $$\limsup_{R \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{|z|=R} \frac{\log \log
>  |f(z)|}{\log R}< \infty$$

…are equivalent. In particular, I have more trouble seeing that the second one implies the first one.

I have never worked with $\sup$‘s before since I’m a Physics major who recently moved into Math so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that the first definition implies the second? Please show how far you got, so that we can better help you.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I’ve shown that. I’ve also shown that the second one implies that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is some $R_0>0$ such that $\forall R \geq R_0$, $\sup_{|z|=R}|f(z)| \leq e^{R^{\lambda+\epsilon}}$, where $\lambda$ is a constant. But I’m not sure if that’s helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the second condition is satisfied:
$$
\limsup_{R \to \infty} \sup_{|z|=R} \frac{\log \log |f(z)|}{\log R} = K < \infty \, .
$$
Then there exists a $R_0 > 0$ such that
$$
\sup_{|z|=R} \frac{\log \log |f(z)|}{\log R} < K+1
$$
for all $R \ge R_0$, i.e.
$$
 \frac{\log \log |f(z)|}{\log |z|} < K+1
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb R$ with $|z| \ge R_0$. This can be rearranged to
$$ 
|f(z)|  e^{-|z|^{K+1}} \le 1
$$
for $|z| \ge R_0$. The left-hand side is continuous and therefore bounded on
the compact disk $|z| \le R_0$, it follows that
$$ 
|f(z)|  e^{-|z|^{K+1}} \le C
$$
for *all* $z \in \Bbb C$ with some constant $C > 0$. Writing this as
$$
|f(z)|  \le  C e^{-|z|^{K+1}} 
$$
shows that the first condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the direction I was pursuing wasn’t the right one?

Comment: @gisame: No, I think you were on the right track. What you perhaps were missing that the condition $\sup_{|z|=R}|f(z)| \leq e^{R^{\lambda+\epsilon}}$ can be made to  hold for *all* $z$ by introducing the additional factor $C$.